# Installing all pyqgis modules without QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, tkinter

I am developing a desktop program with python (tkinter, csv, qgis.core modules, etc), and the idea is to be able to install it in a client's computer.

I have the pyqgis libraries because I have installed QGIS 3.4 in my computer, but I was wondering if I can install just the libraries without installing QGIS, since I want  to be able to install the bare minimum in the client's computer without unnecessary clutter. I think it doesn't look quite professional to install a desktop program and also install a bunch of foreign programs that they are not going to use but "must be there to make mine work".

Can I install just the programming libraries from QGIS (pyqgis) in a computer without installing QGIS and, if so, how?

Comment: First of all, I can't manage to launch any pyqgis program under QGIS 3.4 libraries so far. As to using the programming libraries from QGIS, I can't see much problem. Any application compiled in Visual Studio, for example, requires a certain set of additional libraries depending on functionality let alone a bunch of Microsoft components being referred to implicitly.

Comment: @Vadym What do you mean by not managing to launch any prygis program under QGIS 3.4? Why? I know there is no problem for using the QGIS libraries, I just don't want to install desktop QGIS as well, and I was wondering if there is a way to just install the libraries.

Comment: I'm developing some pyqgis applications using QGIS 3.2. Two times I've made attempts to launch some simple pyqgis under QGIS 3.4 and failed. You can of cause try to use something like cx_Freeze (https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). This tool can make an executable of your python code and theoretically you can select the components of Qgis that are needed for your application.